# How to convert bytearray to pdf and show it with ACTION_VIEW intent

Tags: android, pdf

I am receveving a pdf as an encoded `base64 String`. I would like to show the PDF with ACTION_VIEW intent. How can I do that?

What I have so far is this

```
val byteArray = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT)
val file = FileUtils.createFile(requireContext(), "application/pdf")

val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
fos.write(byteArray)
fos.close()

val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), requireActivity().getString(R.string.file_provider), file)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
startActivity(intent)
```

createFile function looks like

```
fun createFile(context: Context, mimeType: String): File {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val fileName = "TMP_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val suffix = "." + MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType) //.pdf
    return context.getExternalFilesDir("Documents")?.let {
        if (!it.exists()) {
            it.mkdir()
        }
        File.createTempFile(fileName, suffix, it)
    } ?: File.createTempFile(fileName, suffix, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
}
```

The intent starts properly but when I try to open it with a pdf viewer it says the file is corrupted.

Comment: Well save the bytes in the byte array to storage of your device. Then use the created file. But not with Uri.fromFile() but using FileProvider.

Comment: @blackapps thanks! I have updated the description. I am now using FileProvider, but it says the file is corrupted. ( I am confident the byteArray is fine bcz I am able to show it with a 3rd-party library)

Comment: `val file = FileUtils.createFile(requireContext(), "application/pdf")` Remove that line. Dont use FileUtils class. Do not alrerady creat a file. Just create a File instance with the right path. For example in getExternalFilesDir() as you do now. If you have a File instance  FileOutputStream will create the file. `File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Documents), fileName);`.

Comment: `I am confident the byteArray is fine bcz I am able to show it with a 3rd-party library` Very vague. How? But you should be able to show your pdf file with a pdf viewer app. What is file size of pdf file compared to that on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple changed this

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

to

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

works fine now!